# Como permitir que o input() receba notação científica em python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um coeficiente de dilatação térmica que o usuário deve fornecer, exemplo 1.6*10e-5, exatamente este valor, como permitir que o usuário escreva este valor em notação científica?

entrada do coeficiente pelo usuário

```
notação = input('digite a notação')
```

operação

```
multiplica_n = notação * 2

Print(str(multiplica_n))
```

Comment: Não faz sentido modificar a pergunta já que uma pequena variação da resposta soluciona o novo problema: `str_value = str_value.replace("*10", "")`.

Answer (score 2):

A chamada normal para transformar uma string em número decimal - `float`, já converte qualquer número válido em Python para um objeto "float" que é tratado como um número.

E os números válidos incluem números com . decimal, sinal de "-", expoente de notação científica com "e" ou com "E", e os literais "inf" e "nan" - mas não incluem o sinal de vezes com a letra "X" (nem com o caractere unicode "⨉" (N-ARY TIMES OPERATOR"), que é diferente da letra "X"). Isso é, você pode passar "1.6e-5", mas ele não entende "1.6X10e-5" - isso já seria uma conta de vezes explicita.

É importante ter em mente que no caso de um número inválido a chamada a `float`vai dar um erro do tipo "ValueError" - nesse caso é importante combinar um bloco `try/except` junto com um bloco `while` para repetir a entrada.

Então, como exemplos:
`a = '2e5'` cria uma string - se seguiros isso com `print(float(a))`, vamos ver o Python interpretar o "e" como o "e" da notação científica:

```py
In [97]: a = "2e5"                                                                                                           

In [98]: print(float(a))                                                                                                     
200000.0
```

(As marcações 'In[...]' e 'Out[...]' são o prompt do Ipython no modo interativo)

A chamada a `input` sempre retorna uma string (em Python 3 - nas versões antigas da linguagem, até a 2.7, era necessário usar o `raw_input`)

Se você quiser que o símbolo "X" como operador de vezes possa ser usado, pode fazer uma transformação antes da chamada ao `float` para tirar a letra da string - então mesmo que o usuário digitar o número, a entrada continua válida. Para isso, é possível usar o método `.replace` das strings.

Por fim, se for validar a entrada com o `while/try/except` vale a pena colocar o trechinho todo de código numa função - de forma que esse código possa ser reusado para qualquer entrada de float.

```py
def float_input(msg=""):
    retry = True
    while retry:
        str_value = input(msg)
        str_value = str_value.replace("X10", "").replace("x10", "")
        try:
            value = float(str_value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else: 
            # Esse else é do bloco "try": só entra aqui quando não ocorrer erro na chamada ao `float()"
            retry = False
    return value
```

E dá para usar assim:

```py
In [104]: v = float_input("Digite a notação: ")                                                                              
Digite a notação: 1.6X10e-5

In [105]: print(v)                                                                                                           
1.6e-05

In [106]: print(v * 2)                                                                                                       
3.2e-05
```